# how to keep 3d or matrix like grid after calculating the mean for a list of images in python

Tags: python, image-processing, numpy-ndarray, scikit-image

##This is how I uploaded the list of images

```
    import cv2
    import numpy as np
    from matplotlib.image import imread
    import matplotlib.pyplot as plt
    from skimage import color
    import os, subprocess, glob, re
    from PIL import Image
    import glob
    import numpy
```

##this upload data as 11x480x600 shape

```
      list_images = [] 
      for img in glob.glob('../proj/*.jpg'):
          ims = cv2.imread(os.path.join(img))
          list_images.append(ims)
      
      im_arr = numpy.array(list_images)
      im_gry = color.rgb2gray(im_arr)
```

##this code calculates the mean for all images

##but it returns 2d as 480x600

##I need to keep it as 3d or matrix-like

```
       m_df = im_gry.mean(axis=0)
```

##I need to change 3d (1x480x600) into 1d list

##for further processing

##but this does not work as

##m_df.shape[2] is missing

```
    image_shape=m_df[0].shape
    frames_reshaped = m_df.reshape([
    m_df.shape[0]*
    m_df.shape[1],m_df.shape[2]])
    frames_reshaped.shape
```

Comment: [mre] is required.

Comment: @ChristophRackwitz thanks!I added the code that does not work.

Comment: Have you tried https://note.nkmk.me/en/python-numpy-newaxis/ ?